# Removing the levels attribute in output when using pull - R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using dplyr to find the max number of observations in a column. I pipe the data frame, group by the column of interest, summarize using n() to find the number ofobservations for each group, filter the max number of observations out of the groups and then pull the column value. It looks something like this:

```
date_frame %>%
+   group_by(column) %>%
+   summarize(num_observations = n()) %>%
+   filter(num_observations == max(num_observations)) %>%
+   pull(column)
```

When I test each piece, everything seems to work until I pull. This returns both the value I am look for and lists off all of the levels in the column. It looks something like this:

```
[1] value
# Levels: level values...
```

How do I only get it to return only the value I want and not the levels? i.e.:

```
[1] value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `as.character` at the end to convert the `factor` to `character` class

```
library(dplyr)
date_frame %>%
   group_by(column) %>%
   summarize(num_observations = n()) %>%
   filter(num_observations == max(num_observations)) %>%
   pull(column) %>% 
   as.character
```